# Stop animation from array in Unity and C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

In my Unity project I have several levels and several steps. Each step and level have their own animations. With a button click I want to stop all animations, so I tried it the following way. For my project I have two scripts:

**Start_Script.cs**

```
//Steps for Level 01:
public static GameObject Step001, Step011, Step012;    

//Each animation will play in Level 01:
public static Animation AnimationStep001, AnimationStep011, AnimationStep012;  

int levelCounter;

void Awake()
{
    levelCounter = 1;

    Step001 = GameObject.Find("Step001");
    Step011 = GameObject.Find("Step011");
    Step012 = GameObject.Find("Step012");

    AnimationStep001 = Step001.GetComponent<Animation>();
    AnimationStep011 = Step011.GetComponent<Animation>();
    AnimationStep012 = Step012.GetComponent<Animation>();
}

//Method is assigned to "Next Level" Button.
public void nextLevel()
{
    switch(levelCounter) 
    {
        case 1:
            for(int i = 0; i == Array_Lists.animStrings.Length; i++)
            {
                Array_Lists.animAnimation[i].Stop(Array_Lists.animStrings[i]);
            }
            break;
    }
    levelCounter += 1;
}
```

**Array_Lists.cs**

```
// My Array for the animations name:
public static string[] animStrings = {"animStep1", "animStep1.1", "animStep1.2"};

// My Array for the animation objects:
public static Animation[] animAnimation = {
    Start_Script.AnimationStep001,
    Start_Script.AnimationStep011,
    Start_Script.AnimationStep012
};
```

But unfortunately I always get a `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` for `Array_Lists.animAnimation[i].Stop(Array_Lists.animStrings[i]);`

In summary, I need to stop all animations when I hit the "Next Level" Button.

### Edit

After my first `NullReferenceException:` I added a the following to my `public void nextLevel()` method:

```
public void nextLevel()
{
    switch(levelCounter)
    {
        case 1:
            for(int i = 0; i == Array_Lists.animStrings.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.Log("Array Animations = " + Array_Lists.animAnimation[i];

                Debug.Log("Array anim Name = " + Array_Lists.animStrings[i];
                Array_Lists.animAnimation[i].Stop(Array_Lists.animStrings[i]);
            }
            break;
    }
    levelCounter += 1;
}
```

This was my output:

```
Array Animations = null
Array anim Name = animStep1

Array Animations = null
Array anim Name = animStep1.1

Array Animations = null
Array anim Name = animStep1.2
```

Comment: So what variable is it claiming is null?

Comment: @BugFinder see my endings

Comment: Your code is incredibly confusing.  Are you sure your step objects are found? and that they have animations on? It looks like thats a place to start

Comment: yes everyone works fine, I just try to stop all the animations with a click on `Next Level` .. with a click on this button the method `nextLevel()` should start

Comment: Now you're saying it works? that doesnt sound right

Comment: I said that my I am not able to stop all my animations with the Button Next Level. If Level 01 starts, all the animations starts, but they don't stop I I click on Next Level, because I get a NullReferenceExpection

Comment: I dont think the variables are being set like you think they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arrays are static, so they are created before `Awake`.

Your `animAnimation` is filled with nulls, and it doesn't change when you put components to `Start_Script.AnimationStep001` and others. You need to fill `animAnimation` with components after `Awake`. And your scripts are interlinked, this is not very good. Consider creating and populating `animAnimation` from `Start_Script`.

UPD: add this at the end of your `Start_Script.Awake`:

```
Array_Lists.animAnimation = new [] {
    AnimationStep001,
    AnimationStep011,
    AnimationStep012
};
```

Comment: I think I am doing it all wrong, I am not able to bring it to work without an NullReferenceException.

Comment: @diem_L try a snippet I added to my answer

Comment: if I try this the following error will be shown `Start_Script.cs(52,29): error CS1002: ; expected`

Comment: @diem_L it's hard to tell where exactly the semicolon is missing without seeing the whole script, inspect 52th line

Comment: if I use you code from UPD, then the `{ ` , the `, ` and the `} ` are red underlined and each error says  `Invalid expression "{" , ";" expected`

Comment: @diem_L yeah, I forgot about `new`, check my upd

Answer (score 2):

```
i == Array_Lists.animStrings.Length
```

and not

```
i < Array_Lists.animStrings.Length
```

I suspect you never enter the for cycle.

Comment: thanks for the advice .. but unfortunately I still get the NullReferenceException